# problems about OpenGL glGeneratemipmap and glGetTexImage

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

I form a 256*256 image,and I want to use the glGeneratemipmap function to generate 3-level mipmap,then use the glGetTexImage function to get the 2rd level mipmap data，the data I want to should be 64*64,but it turned to be 128*128,here is my code， what's wrong with the code,can you help me？

```
 // image data：
int bytePerline1 = 256 * 24 / 8;
unsigned char *mipmapImage=new unsigned char[256*bytePerline1];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
    {
        mipmapImage[i*bytePerline1 + j * 3 + 0] = 255;
        mipmapImage[i*bytePerline1 + j * 3 + 1] = 255;
        mipmapImage[i*bytePerline1 + j * 3 + 2] = 0;

    }
int glwidth = 256;
int glheight = 256;
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, glwidth, glheight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mipmapImage);//load the data to gpu
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 3);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);//generate mipmap
int bytePerLine2 = (64 * 24) / 8;
unsigned char *result = new unsigned char[bytePerLine2 * 64];
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, result);//get the 2rd level mipmap data
```

I am using  the QImage class of QT to form the image.Here is the code:

```
int bytePerLine2 = (64 * 24) / 8;
unsigned char *result = new unsigned char[bytePerLine2 * 64];
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, result);//get the 2rd level mipmap data
if (result != NULL)
{
    int bytePerLine3 = (64 * 24 + 31) / 8;
    unsigned char * result1 = new unsigned char[bytePerLine3 * 64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
        {
            result1[i*bytePerLine3 + j * 3] = *result;
            result1[i*bytePerLine3 + j * 3+1] = *(result+1);
            result1[i*bytePerLine3 + j * 3 + 2] = *(result + 2);
            result = result + 3;
        }
    QImage *image = new QImage(result1, 64, 64, bytePerLine3, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    char * path = "C:\\Users\\hao\\Desktop\\temp1.jpg";
    image->save(path);
    delete image;
    image = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: "*but it turned to be 128*128*" What makes you say that?

Comment: @NicolBolas,because I use the  glGetTexImage function get the  2rd level mipmap data and then form a jpg image,the image's height and width are both 128.But the original  image texture image data is 256*256.the 2rd level mipmap's width and height should be 64.

Comment: "*then form a jpg image*" With what? If you are using some library function to take a block of pixels and compress it with JPEG, then you *must* be telling that function what the width/height of your pixel data is. I know of no image library that will *infer* the size of the pixel data from merely a pointer. So why are you telling your JPEG library the wrong size? And if you think I'm wrong about you giving it the wrong size, then show the code where you convert your copied pixel data into a JPEG.

Comment: @NicolBolas. yes,you are right, I am using some library fuction.I am using the QImage class of QT to form the image.I edit  my question,you can see the code.Thank you for your patience.